# jquery parseInt comparison not working

Tags: jquery

I have two numbers in jquery. Eg: 45 & 55. I pass these numbers in parseInt. But when going to compare the max number it always return false.

```
var data = parseInt(data);
var quantity = parseInt(quantity);

console.log(data < quantity); and
console.log(data > quantity);
```

Both return false. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a string that doesn't start with a numeral to `parseInt`, it'll return `NaN`.

```
NaN < NaN
```

will always be false (the same is true even if only one of them is `NaN`).

---

You'll have to check your variables to make sure they're not `NaN`:

```
var data = parseInt(data);
var quantity = parseInt(quantity);

if ( isNaN(data) ) data = 0;
if ( isNaN(quantity) ) quantity = 0;
```

Comment: This data variable is passed from ajax as html. How can I convert it to a number. When I check the typeof data it returns 'object'

Comment: @Priyanga - What do you get when you log the variable?

Comment: After I have done few changes now it logs a number. It's type also number

Answer (score 0):

All depends what do you have in that variables!

I try assigning 45 and 55 respectively and one was true and the other false. But if you try the same numbre, then both are false.